# Compare execution time of two similar TSQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 sql queries. The 2nd one is a modified version of the 1st one and there only little difference between them.

I want to know the execution time of both sqls, so I gave like

**--Query 1**

```
set statistics time on
    Select...
    .........
set statistics time off

--Result
(2 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 39 ms.
```

**--Query 2**

```
set statistics time on
    Select...
    .........
set statistics time off

--Result
(2 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

For the 2nd Query, the elapsed time is 0 ms, It should be some where around the execution time of 1st sql. It gave 0 ms ,just because I executed [Query 1] before [Query 2].
How can I view the elapsed time of 2nd query, should I delete statistics or any thing?

Comment: "*Advanced Querying including window-functions, dynamic-sql, and query-performance*" can go in http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @huMpty duMpty none of those are apparent in the question

Comment: @Used_By_Already: execution time is probably related with *query-performance*

Comment: possible duplicate: please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764011/compare-two-queries note in particular the comment by AdaTheDev; you want to clear chaces between running queries, and if possible run several times in different sequence

Comment: @huMpty duMpty it isn't actually about the queries or their performance, it is about how to compare (TSQL) queries. It could go to dba I guess but it's a previously answered question anyway.

Comment: check this link http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/12/05/sql-server-finding-frequently-running-query-and-elapsed-time-notes-from-the-field-005/

Comment: Just put them in the same batch and do estimate query plan. Look at the relative costs. `</question>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `last_execution_time` column in [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) will contain the information. Also it can be captured as the `Duration` column of the [`SQL:StmtCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189886.aspx) event in SQL Profiler.

That being said, there are more ways to compare queries, not just time. Logical Reads, IO and wait stats come to mind. I recommend you read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/) for details how to measure, what to measure and how to compare queries.

Comment: Thanks Remus, The link is very useful.

Comment: Does [execution_count] column gives the execution time in ms?

Comment: `execution_count` is *Number of times that the plan has been executed since it was last compiled.* as documented in the link

Comment: last_worker_time = 80 Means, when it was executed last time, it took 80 milli sec. is that right?

Comment: No, that would be `last_elapsed_time`. I recommend you read more carefully the documentation linked.

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31002/what-is-difference-between-last-worker-time-and-last-elapsed-time-in-dmv-sys-dm for an explanation of `worker` vs. `elapsed` times.

Comment: I am sorry, I got repeatedly confused with the column last_execution_time. I found out the last_elapsed_time column.
Thanks, once again